# How to manage the data without database?

Tags: c#

In my folder having many photos. I want to create photo comment. its like orkut. How to manage the commented data without db as per image.

Answer (score 3):

You can use XML for storing comments. Why not use DB? Managing XML files for large number of photos will be pain. You can try out [SQLIte](http://www.sqlite.org/) which is compact and will serve your purpose.

Comment: For many pics, and many comments, such an xml file can become very large. DB would be great, or comment file per pic? might be over kill, bu tshould be relatively small files per pic

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/). Its a lightweight database that lives in a single file, so you dont have to set up a database server, but you get to leverage all of the sql libraries out there and quickly build up your system.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the comment into the vb++ image metadata processor and store the comment in binary format with the encryption in side the image with the comment.  You could even put the link to the image in the metadata for the image so you can find the image from the metadata.